# ¿Como escribir símbolos especiales?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Mientras estaba usando python, intente pegar el Símbolo de la raíz cuadrada.

```
print "√"
Error Unsupported characters in input
```

¿Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: NoCUBes ¿Esto te ocurre por casualidad en Windows usando la **shell** del interprete interactivo del **IDLE**? Me suena que habia un bug al respecto. Da algo de mas información, no tiene pinta de ser un problema tiipico de encoding usando el interprete en CMD/terminal o ejecutando un script... De igual manera recomiendo dejar de lado Python 2, en la actualidad todos las bibliotecas importantes están para Python 3. Python 2 además de la problemática de encoding que genera pasará a mejor vida en en 2020, no tiene mucho sentido usarlo para aprender y menos en producción.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes colocar la siguiente linea al inicio de tu archivo:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

Para más información, esta pregunta fue respondida aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873543/unsupported-characters-in-input